# How do I use ffmpeg to get the video resolution?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

I am trying to get resolution of the video with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4
```

I get a long output, but I need just the width and height for my bash script. How should I filter out those parameters? Maybe there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 122):

## Use `ffprobe`

For example:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 input.mp4
```

Output in the format:

```
1280x720
```

---

### Examples of other output formatting choices

[See `-of` option documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers) for more choices and options. Also see [FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for other examples including duration and frame rate.

#### Default With No `[STREAM]` Wrapper

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=nw=1 input.mp4
```

Output in the format:

```
width=1280
height=720
```

#### Default With No Key

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp4
```

Output in the format:

```
1280
720
```

#### CSV

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

Output in the format:

```
1280,720
```

#### JSON

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of json input.mp4
```

Output in the format:

```json
{
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
        }
    ]
}
```

#### XML

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of xml input.mp4
```

Output in the format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ffprobe>
    <programs>
    </programs>

    <streams>
        <stream width="1280" height="720"/>
    </streams>
</ffprobe>
```

Comment: Using `eval` is risky and not really necessary for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: @bariumbitmap Thanks. `eval` in the answer has been eliminated for a super simple solution that I somehow missed despite staring at the documentation for years.

Comment: I got two result with that command `{
    "programs": [
        {
            "streams": [
                {
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 360
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "width": 640,
            "height": 360
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @SalemF Append `| sort -nur | head -n 1`. This returns the resolution with the largest width. That being said, in all cases I've ever seen, there is only one resolution, but that may be duplicated.

Comment: Could you please advise how to get simple output of the video length? Thanks

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ See [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604)

Comment: @llogan - I would like to print them together (resolution and sexagesimal length) with running `ffprobe` just once. Possible?

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ `ffprobe -v error -sexagesimal -show_entries stream=width,height:format=duration -of default=nw=1 input.mp4`

Comment: @llogan - I used `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,duration -of csv=s=x:p=0 -sexagesimal input.mp4`, but I would like to change separator `s=x` to a standard space character. I cannot find documentation how to use space character in `csv` parameter. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ `-of "csv=s=\ :p=0"`

Comment: @llogan - Genius! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 10):

The following commands rely purely on `ffmpeg` (and `grep` and `cut`) to get you the height or width as required:

Width:

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Video: | grep -Po '\d{3,5}x\d{3,5}' | cut -d'x' -f1
```

`1280`

Height:

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Video: | grep -Po '\d{3,5}x\d{3,5}' | cut -d'x' -f2
```

`720`

The difference between the two is just the `-f` parameter to `cut`.

If you prefer the full resolution string, you don't need `cut`:

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Video: | grep -Po '\d{3,5}x\d{3,5}'
```

`1280x720`

Here's what we're doing with these commands:

1. Running `ffmpeg -i` to get the file info.
2. Extracting the line which just contains `Video:` information.
3. Extracting just a string that looks like `digitsxdigits` which are between 3 and 5 characters.
4. For the first two, cutting out the text before or after the `x`.

Comment: The output from ffmpeg is only meant for human eyes, and not meant to be parsed by scripts or other tools. The output is not standardized and so it is not guaranteed to be the same format for all files, so it is a fragile use case. Use ffprobe instead. Lots of examples here in this thread.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I agree, but this is an option for those who do not wish to `ffprobe` for whatever reason.

Comment: Also your code play the whole file if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 3):

The output of `ffprobe` looks like this:

```
streams_stream_0_width=1280
streams_stream_0_height=720
```

Technically, you can use `eval`
to assign these to `bash` variables,
but this is not necessary
and can be unsafe; see here for more:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Instead, since you are using `bash`, take advantage of its built-in arrays and string manipulation:

```bash
filepath="filename.mp4"
width_prefix='streams_stream_0_width='
height_prefix='streams_stream_0_height='
declare -a dimensions
while read -r line
do
    dimensions+=( "${line}" )
done < <( ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height "${filepath}" )
width_with_prefix=${dimensions[0]}
height_with_prefix=${dimensions[1]}
width=${width_with_prefix#${width_prefix}}
height=${height_with_prefix#${height_prefix}}
printf "%s\t%sx%s\n" "${filepath}" "${width}" "${height}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *grep* to select only those lines you are looking for. Redirect the output from STDERR to STDOUT, since ffmpeg will output all info there.

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 2>&1 | grep <keyword>
```

Edit: A full working example using perl:

```
$ ffmpeg -i MVI_7372.AVI 2>&1 | grep Video | perl -wle 'while(<>){ $_ =~ /.*?(\d+x\d+).*/; print $1 }'
640x480
```

Comment: You also need to use STDERR. I fixed that part.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer:

I used this [package called Media info](https://launchpad.net/~shiki/+archive/ubuntu/mediainfo)

And then I commanded:

```
mediainfo mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%" midhand.mp4
```

To view the list of params:

```
mediainfo --Info-Parameters
```

Best tool to extract video metadata!

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is about bash but, just in case someone ends here looking for a solution for a Windows batch, as myself before I found it out.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ffprobe -hide_banner -show_streams filename.mp4 2^>nul ^| findstr "^width= ^height="') do set "myvideo_%%a"
```

No console messages, and you end with the nice environment variables `myvideo_width` and `myvideo_height`. You can check it with:

```
C:\>set myvideo_
myvideo_height=720
myvideo_width=1280
```

If the resolution of your video is 1280x720, of course.

Answer (score 1):

edit: **FFPROBE solution** for windows batch. Use this instead of the FFMPEG-only method, because that's parsing input meant for humans and it broke on me.

```
 ::Gets resolution
 for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('"ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 "input.mp4""') do (set videoRes=%%g)

 echo videoRes=%videoRes%

 ::OPTIONAL: Gets individual x and y resolutions if you want that
 for /f "tokens=1 delims=x" %%x in ("%videoRes%") do set "xRes=%%x"
 for /f "tokens=2 delims=x" %%y in ("%videoRes%") do set "yRes=%%y"

 echo xRes=%xRes%
 echo yRes=%yRes%
```

---

**FFMPEG-only solution** for windows batch.  Don't use because it's brittle.  It probably only works if you only have 1 video stream in the file, you'll have to alter it if there are more.

```
@echo off >nul 2>&1
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion >nul 2>&1

for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('"ffmpeg -i input.mp4 2>&1 | findstr Video:"') do (set videoInfo=%%g)
for /f "tokens=4 delims=," %%g in ("!videoInfo!") do set "videoInfo=%%g"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=x " %%x in ("!videoInfo!") do set "xRes=%%x"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=x " %%y in ("!videoInfo!") do set "yRes=%%y"

echo xRes=!xRes!
echo yRes=!yRes!
```