# Randomly select 10 seconds from mp3 files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, audio-conversion

I have a directory `tracks` with 3 files `track1.mp3`, `track2.mp3`, `track3.mp3`. I want to select a random chunk of 10 seconds from each file and combine these chunks into a new file called `sample.mp3`. How do I do this using ffmpeg?

I am pretty new to ffmpeg and all I managed to do so far is splitting a file into chunks

`ffmpeg -i track1.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 10 -c copy out%03d.mp3`

Someone, please help. I am on Mac OSX high sierra and bash shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following bash script:

```
numFiles=3
maxStart=10
idx=1
for randomStart in $(jot -r $numFiles 0 $maxStart); do
    ffmpeg -y -ss "$randomStart" -i "track${idx}.mp3" -t 10 -c:a copy "track${idx}-chunk.mp3"
    idx=$((idx + 1))
done
```

Here, you have to specify the number of files (`track1` through `track3`) and the maximum start position (e.g., if your files are only 20 seconds long, you should at most start from 00:00:10).

The `jot` utility is used to create random numbers between 0 and `$maxStart` (i.e., 10 in the above example). On Linux, `jot` is not available; instead use `shuf -n $numFiles -i 0-$maxStart`.

Then, concatenate the chunks (see the [FFmpeg Wiki entry](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*-chunk.mp3; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.mp3
```

It uses special shell syntax to construct a temporary concatenation file. This will copy the bitstreams, so no re-encoding is done.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. You have been very helpful, I have no means of knowing the length of my files beforehand

Comment: In this case you would have to approach it differently: iterate through the files, run a first pass with ffmpeg or ffprobe to [get their length in seconds](https://superuser.com/a/945604/48078), and use that to generate a new random number for the maximum start position. But that's where I'd stop using Bash and use Python or Ruby instead.