# FFmpeg - split up mp4 with variable duration into two equal parts

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to split up a video into 2 equal parts.

The problem is that video could be any duration. E.g. 3 seconds, 3.5 seconds or more.

I could only find a solution to split up a video if you know exact duration.

Is it possible to achieve the same result for a video with variable duration?

With FFmpeg on Windows.

Comment: Windows or some kind of *nix?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Windows.

Comment: There are free products on Windows which can do video split into equal parts, other than FFmpeg. For example: [Bandicut Video Splitter](https://www.bandicam.com/video-splitter/) and [SolveigMM Video Splitter](http://www.solveigmm.com/en/howto/how-to-slice-video-by-time-size-or-parts-with-video-splitter/). Let me know if you are interested in such an alternative solution.

Comment: You can extract/calculate the whole video time then divide it by 2 and use the result  with the correct format for the `-ss` and `-to` options (in the two `ffmpeg` invocations: extract the first half, extract the second one) .  You can even use the number of frames...for example you can count it  with `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -` then with `grep` and `awk` select the output...divide by 2 etc etc...

Comment: Even more efficiently with the segment `-f segment -segment_time ` then the time... you have only to extract it in advance. OS depending...

Comment: Do you just need the `ffmpeg` commands to do this, or is this a two-in-one question and do you expect the answer to also include batch scripting? (I know the commands, but not the batch.)

Answer (score 1):

You can split up video files by this command :

```
ffmpeg -i largefile.mp4 -t 00:50:00 -c copy smallfile1.mp4 -ss 00:50:00 -c copy smallfile2.mp4
```

Find the current duration of the file with this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

Now calculate the half of it and put the value in previous code.

I can Create a script in bash But you are using windows. however, you can use a bash script if you are using Windows 10.

Comment: This splits the file at 50 minutes from the start, not in half.

Comment: The output from `ffmpeg` is not meant to be machine parsed. [Use `ffprobe` instead](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Formatcontainerduration) ([more examples](https://superuser.com/questions/650291/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds/945604#945604)). Doing so will also allow you to omit `grep`, `cut`, and `sed`.