# Use FFMPEG to automagically work out crossfades

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to create seamless loops with FFMPEG but am unsure of the right way of approaching it.

If I can pseudocode it out for y'all would someone be able to help me with the correct invocation?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 --get-midway-point --put-second-half-of-film-first --put-first-half-of-film-second --overlap-part1-and-part2-by-n-milliseconds ---transition-transparency-from-100-to-0-over-n-milliseconds -o output.mp4
```

I'm sort of presuming that it's possible but I'm really stumped.

Comment: Currently this requires scripting, so answer depends on your OS or preferred scripting language. Or wait for the pending [crossfade filter patch](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2019-October/252027.html) to get applied and it will make things easier.

Comment: Aha, great. So I should break it down into each task and make a shell script or python script then.

Thanks for answering, I'll be sure to report back if I get it worked out.

Comment: @llogan Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JakeGould Sure, but I was waiting for the OP to tell me the OS so I could possibly come up with a turnkey answer.

Comment: @llogan You should just post an answer and edit for the OS specifics after that is clarified. Take credit!

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be scripted, but I'm unsure of your OS/shell/scripting language so I can't give you a turnkey answer to copy and paste. Here are the basic steps:

1. [Get duration of input](https://superuser.com/a/945604/110524).
2. Divide the result in half. [Example using `bc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35026487/1109017).
3. Create segments with (a)trim filters.
4. [Crossfade](https://superuser.com/a/834035/110524)

Comment: Sorry yes, I should have stated I was on Mac.