# FFMPEG - Merge two audio file with defined overlapping time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

**Requirement**

I'd like to concat two audio files with predefined overlapping time.

For instance, if 10 sec overlapping is defined, then the ending 10sec of first audio and the starting 10sec of second audio are overlapped in the output.

```
|<---- 1st mp3 file -------------------->                       |
|                        <-----------2nd mp3 file ------------->|

result:
|<-----------------------(overlap 10 sec )--------------------->|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use [`ffprobe` to get duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/110524) of 1st mp3 file.
2. Run `ffmpeg` using [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) to delay the audio and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) to mix the two audio streams into one:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=Ns|Ns[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3
   ```

   - `Ns` = `1.mp3 duration` - `overlap duration`. For example, if `1.mp3` is 30 seconds long, and you want a 10 second overlay, then use `20s|20s`.
   - This assumes `2.mp3` is stereo.
   - If you `ffmpeg` is older than version 4.2 then use milliseconds instead of seconds in adelay, as in `20000|20000`.
   - `-map "[a]"` tells `ffmpeg` to use the output from amix which is arbitrarily labeled `[a]`. Otherwise, the [default stream selection behavior](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) will be used. If you are fine with that and understand the implications then feel free to omit the label and `-map` (such as `...amix=inputs=2" output.mp3`). Also see [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems working! Would you mind to explain the usage of adelay and amix in this command, especially the `-map` meaning?

Comment: @XiXiao See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already made good progress.

Comment: I see two issues, 1) the output mp3 file is compressed with only 1/2 original size, 2) the volume of the content before the `adelay` timestamp is much lower than the original, not sure why it is like this.

Comment: @XiXiao 1) File size is not a reliable metric. The inputs may not have been encoded efficiently, or they may have a huge bitrate. More importantly, it's not a direct comparison as the output is a merge of the two individual inputs (and possibly with double the number of channels). 2) amix lowers the volume to accommodate all inputs to prevent clipping. You can add the volume or dynaudnorm filters (optionally with `enable` option). There are several Q/A on this site or [so] that deal with that.

Comment: Thanks @llogan your comments are really helpful to me!