# FFMPEG filter_complex - merge audio files without losing quality and volume

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I want to merge two audio files with **defined overlapping time**, and the command is by help of [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1509582/ffmpeg-merge-two-audio-file-with-defined-overlapping-time):

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=Ns|Ns[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3
```

The issues are

1. the output file size is only ~1/2 original size (quality lost)
2. the audio volume before `adepaly` timestamp is reduced a lot. Not sure why.

I perceive that it needs decoding when using `-filter_complex`, but I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve overlapping without decoding

Comment: Add volume=2 after the amix.

Comment: ehh.. why `volume=2`?  And how about the decoding part? @Gyan

Comment: amix downscales volume as per number of inputs, so add volume filter to restore it. Filters only work on decoded data, no way around that.

Comment: Thanks for the volume part! Do you mean there is no way in ffmpeg to overlap two inputs while keeping the quality? Are there other command-line tools that can achieve it? @Gyan

Comment: Save to a lossless format. ffmpeg uses LAME for MP3 encoding; so will most other tools. If you want to maintain original file size, add a bitrate arg which matches the original e.g. : `-b:a 256k`.