# Insert audio at the beginning and end of a video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a single video (~10 mins) and two audio files (~2 mins each). I want to add one audio file to the beginning and the other one to the end of the video keeping the middle of the video silent. Can this be accomplished without re-encoding (at least the video) and, if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods to do this.

## apad + concat filter

Use [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) to extend audio1 with silent audio, and then [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) to concatenate it with audio2:

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio1 -i audio2 -filter_complex "[1:a]apad=pad_dur=360[a1];[a1][2:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output.mp4
```

## anullsrc + concat demuxer

This can allow you to avoid re-encoding anything but it is slightly more complicated as it takes several steps. Note that all inputs must have the same format, channel layout, and sample rate.

1. Make 8 minute silence with [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc):

   ```
   ffmpeg -f lafvi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -t 00:08:00 silence.m4a
   ```
2. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 'audio1.m4a'
   file 'silence.m4a'
   file 'audio2.m4a'
   ```
3. Concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f concat -i input.txt -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mp4
   ```

## adelay + amix

You can use [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) to add a delay to audio2, and then downmix audio1 and audio2 with [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix):

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio1 -i audio2 -filter_complex "[2:a]adelay=480s:all=1[a2];[1:a][a2]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output.mp4
```

- You will need at least FFmpeg 4.2 to use this newer adelay syntax. Otherwise you will have to declare the delay in milliseconds and do so for each individual channel (each separated by a `|`).
- Note that the output will be affected by audio volume normalization. This means that it will be quieter than its individual segments. See [amix filter volume issue with inputs of different duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509147/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-issue-with-inputs-of-different-duration/49712495#49712495) for various solutions.

---

#### Getting durations

You can use [`ffprobe` to get the durations](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) of each input which is especially helpful for scripted usage.