# How to merge two uncertain audio files, which may be mono or stereo, into one stereo file using FFmpeg？

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

input:

> Two audio file, It may be stereo or mono.

output:

> - A stereo file, and the stereo FL uses one file all channels, and FR uses other file all channels.
> - The total duration is based on the longest file.
> - I hope it can be achieved through FFmpeg.

There are four case:

- mono + mono -> stereo
- mono + stereo -> stereo
- stereo + mono -> stereo
- stereo + stereo -> stereo

I hope someone can help me, I am a newbie to FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Get duration of each input with `ffprobe`](https://superuser.com/a/945604/110524) to determine which audio is shortest.
2. Convert each input to mono with the [aformat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) filter.
3. Apply the [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) filter to the shorter input.
4. Join multiple input streams into one multi-channel stream with the [join](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join) filter.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono:sample_rates=44100,apad[a0];[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono:sample_rates=44100[a1];[a0][a1]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" output
```

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation).

Comment: You are such a genius, thank you very much！！！